# Laravel 5.7 Autocomplete search from DB: JS not recognizing the route

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4ny-CboZC0

I've done everything, but at the time of testing I get the following error in the console:

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST
http://apr2.test/admin/posts/%7B%7B%20('autocomplete.fetch')%20%7D%7D
404 (Not Found)
```

One thing I'm doing different is that **I want that search functionality inside my page of post creation, not an exclusive one**, so my *routes* are like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');    
   Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index')->name('admin.posts.index');
   Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create')->name('admin.posts.create');
   Route::post('posts/create', 'PostsController@fetch')->name('autocomplete.fetch');
   Route::post('posts', 'PostsController@store')->name('admin.posts.store');
});
```

My JS/jQuery code:

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#country_name').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        if (query != '') {
            var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ ('autocomplete.fetch') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query,
                    _token: _token
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#countryList').fadeIn();
                    $('#countryList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'li', function () {
        $('#country_name').val($(this).text());
        $('#countryList').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from the blade where you are using the route name as `%7B%7B` in a url is translated to `{{`.

Please double check you're using the right code there, or in the action tag in your form element: `{{ route ("autocomplete.fetch") }}` and it's not being lost by some quotes.

Comment: Based on the tutorial I'm following, it is inside an .ajax function. I added the code in the question.

Comment: @dawn Is your JS in a blade template? The {{}} are used for blade and it "compiles" to php code. It seems its not in a blade template and javascript sees it as text.

Comment: @Hawiak Okai, I moved that script into the HTML itself, and that error is gone, but now I get `jquery.min.js:2 POST http://apr2.test/admin/posts/create 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: That's a coding error, Chrome will help you troubleshoot if in your page you go on Inspector > Network, refresh your page and click on the error when it appears. It should show where the error is coming from and what it is.